# Change the default font size and font name in CKEDITOR

Tags: ckeditor

I am using CKEditor in my project. The requirement is to make the font name and font size changed dynamically based on user settings which we configure in one place. I am looking for a suitable solution which helps me to change the fonts in CKEditor. I had done some modification in the config using the 
Have tried [Is there a way to set the default font and font-size in CKEditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142277/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-default-font-and-font-size-in-ckeditor?rq=1) but no luck
Any help will be always appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [`contentsCss`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss). Which will load your css rules to editor's content.
Example what you can do with that you can find here: https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/styles.html