# CKEditor (default) item in Font Name and Size dropdown

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

In the sample of CKEditor, the Font Name and Font Size dropdown have a item which is (default), which gives user to change the Font Name and Size back to the default setting.

Which when choose the default item in these two dropdown, the span created for specifying Font Name and Size was removed when we inspect the source of the content.

[image]

source: https://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/index.html

However, when i google through how to set this configuration, the normal answer is to set the default label, which can't achieve the effect shown in the sample.

May i ask how to set the configuration in order to achieve the same effect shown in the example?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any update on this question? @programmingBaka

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you meant but if you are asking how to set default font through JavaScript then the answer is you can't do that. The default font can only be set in `ckeditor/contents.css` (look for the `body` element definition) for classic editor or main page CSS file for inline editor.

If you have set default font (inside your CSS) to `Times New Roman`, you can also set default font label to the same value so that default font is being shown whenever there is no matching font in current selection. Please see:

- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-font_defaultLabel
- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-font_names

Same can be done for Font Size:

- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-fontSize_defaultLabel
- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-fontSize_sizes

Please note that font dropdowns are not fully context sensitive meaning they only show given font name or size if there is an exact match. If CKEditor sets e.g. `<span style="font-family:Courier New,Courier,monospace">test</span>` the Font Dropdown will only display name `Courier New` if you have exactly `span` element with `Courier New,Courier,monospace` as `font-family` value inside set in your HTML. In all other cases "Default" label or default font name (if you have set [font_defaultLabel](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-font_defaultLabel)) will be shown. This of course can lead to problems when you paste fonts (e.g. from MS Word) which are not defined in dropdown definition. In such a case editor will show invalid values because it will use Default label or default font name.

Problem can be worked around with the help of Advanced Content Filter (ACF) and [addTransformations](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_filter.html#method-addTransformations) method. I have explained it briefly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50907085/4555078).

Hope this helps.