# Changing default font size of Ckeditor's textarea

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

So there seems to be many questions about this, but not sure if there are any solutions on the latest Ckeditor version 4. I'm simply trying to change the default font from Times New Roman, and I have access to the `editor.css` file of the skin that I'm using.

Some suggestions that I've tried without any success are adding this to the `editor.css` file:

```
body, p {
    font-family: "open sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(41, 41, 42);
    font-size: 13px;
    color: rgb(103, 106, 108);
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I've also tried to add this into the `config.js` file of CKeditor:

```
config.contentsCss = ["body {font-size: 20px;}"]
```

within the `CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) { }` block, as well as adding this underneath it:

```
CKEDITOR.config.font_defaultLabel = 'Arial';
CKEDITOR.config.fontSize_defaultLabel = '28px';
```

Still no luck. Not quite sure why this is so difficult. Any suggestions?

I've even added a "catch all" in the `editor.css` and that still doesn't work:

```
* {
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: Arial;
}
```

That affects literally everything on the site **except** for what's in the textbox of the texteditor. Now mind you the `fullPage` option is enabled, resulting in the textarea being in an `iframe`, but not sure if that would make a difference.

I've tried solutions from the other stackoverflow questions, but they still do not change the font size within the text editor, just everything else.

** EDIT **

So here's what my texteditor looks like:

[image]

This is what each texteditor looks like by default, so apparently changing the `contents.css` file isn't affecting it. I guess I need to figure out why there's no reference to the `contents.css` file in the `head` tag of the HTML document.

Comment: Do you have the Ckeditor as a file because if so you could change it inside of the file.

Comment: I'm using the `ckeditor-rails` gem and importing the css/js from within the application.js/css file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to set the default font and font-size in CKEditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142277/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-default-font-and-font-size-in-ckeditor)

Comment: Tried that, but doesn't appear to work either. The fonts outside of the ckeditor change, but not what's in it.

Answer (score 1):

The [contentsCss](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-contentsCss) points to CSS file which is used to style editor content area for classic editor (inline editor is part of page so you need to add appropriate styles to that page to style editor contents). By default this file is located in `ckeditor/contents.css`. Please simply open that file, find definition for `body` element, change `font-family` to value you want to use. Next find the definition for `.cke_editable` (this class is being assigned to body element) and change `font-size` to value you want to use. Below is the sample configuration and the result.

```
body
{
    /* Font */
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
    font-size: 12px;

    /* Text color */
    color: #333;

    /* Remove the background color to make it transparent. */
    background-color: #fff;

    margin: 20px;
}

.cke_editable
{
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 1.6;

    /* Fix for missing scrollbars with RTL texts. (#10488) */
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[image]

What may be confusing is that dropdowns don't react to styles from external CSS files. They only react to inline styles assigned to HTML elements and only if there is an exact match (they are not fully context sensitive). You can however verify default font being used with browser dev-tools.

Comment: I just modified the  `ckeditor/contents.css` file to just include "Trebuchet MS", and changed the font size. Those changes were not reflected when refreshing the text editor. I increased the font size to `30px` and it's still the same in the text editor.

Comment: Based on inspecting the document, it looks like there is no CSS that is modifying the actual contents of the text editor when it is an iframe. Seems like I'd have to set that within the iframe itself. Or if I could replace the default `<body></body>` with `<body style=xyz>`

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you that it works. First of all if you are using classic editor `contents.css` are attached to internal document by default. If you haven't changed https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-contentsCss then it has to work.

Comment: Second if you want to change `font-size`, you need to edit `.cke_editable` class which has `font-size` already defined. This class is being assigned to `body` element and as you know definition for class has higher priority than definition for element so either change `font-size` there or remove `font-size` from there and define it in the `body`. Please see: https://marksheet.io/css-priority.html

Comment: Finally, this is CSS so it may happen that something got cached. Please make sure that cache is cleared properly. Here is a good article explaining how to do it: https://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cache. 
If the above fails, please make sure that you are using classic CKEditor with contents in iframe and not e.g. divarea or inline editor for which styles should be defined in CSS for your main page as these editors are part of page. Please also check if `contentsCss` isn't changed in anyway.

Comment: Thanks. So your screenshot shows the style referencing a spreadsheet. Mine doesn't, and I don't know why. Maybe that's why it's not working? Why would my `<style>` element only have some static text? I'll update the post with a screenshot of what I can se.

Comment: Sorry, not the style tag, but the `head` element doesn't have any references to any stylesheets according to me inspecting the document (screenshot above)

Comment: Please check your editor configuration. If you have changed `contentsCss` setting then styles will not be referenced. This would be the first place to check for me. You have written in your original post that you are `using config.contentsCss = ["body {font-size: 20px;}"]`. This is very bad. Please read the first sentence of my answer and visit link to contentsCSS I have put there so that you know how to properly configure this setting. Basically you should be setting paths to CSS files there and not particular styles.

Answer (score 1):

Added to html code and it worked:

`<script>  CKEDITOR.addCss(".cke_editable { font-size: 16px;}"); </script>`

Answer (score 0):

After what seems like forever and a day, I simply added this to my custom `config.js` file:

```
CKEDITOR.addCss("body {font-size: 10px}");
```

and this solved my issue.